# Get road location from text via google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have a free text that I need to convert into coordinates, but the text aim to roads and roads injections.

**The problem is that google api geocoding service return the nearby buildings but I need the road themselfs.**

for example:
Searching for us95 and sunset in las vegas returns

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "U.S. 95",
               "short_name" : "US-95",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Whitney Ranch",
               "short_name" : "Whitney Ranch",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Henderson",
               "short_name" : "Henderson",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Clark County",
               "short_name" : "Clark County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nevada",
               "short_name" : "NV",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "89014",
               "short_name" : "89014",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "US-95 & W Sunset Rd, Henderson, NV 89014, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0636796,
                  "lng" : -115.0334434
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0632289,
                  "lng" : -115.033988
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.0635045,
               "lng" : -115.0336492
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0648032302915,
                  "lng" : -115.0323667197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0621052697085,
                  "lng" : -115.0350646802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJf0Azwu_QyIARci-cUiUBGMg",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "U.S. 95",
               "short_name" : "US-95",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Henderson",
               "short_name" : "Henderson",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Clark County",
               "short_name" : "Clark County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nevada",
               "short_name" : "NV",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "89011",
               "short_name" : "89011",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "US-95 & W Sunset Rd, Henderson, NV 89011, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0616173,
                  "lng" : -115.029007
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0591372,
                  "lng" : -115.0301591
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.0603734,
               "lng" : -115.0295973
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0617262302915,
                  "lng" : -115.0282340697085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0590282697085,
                  "lng" : -115.0309320302915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJmZvnMeTQyIARi5giBwp9Ylc",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "U.S. 95",
               "short_name" : "US-95",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Whitney Ranch",
               "short_name" : "Whitney Ranch",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Henderson",
               "short_name" : "Henderson",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Clark County",
               "short_name" : "Clark County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nevada",
               "short_name" : "NV",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "89014",
               "short_name" : "89014",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "US-95 & W Sunset Rd, Henderson, NV 89014, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.065207,
                  "lng" : -115.0334417
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0648819,
                  "lng" : -115.0334889
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.065045,
               "lng" : -115.0334589
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.06639343029149,
                  "lng" : -115.0321163197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0636954697085,
                  "lng" : -115.0348142802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJ5bnQNO7QyIAReqWyr22kKYc",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "U.S. 95",
               "short_name" : "US-95",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Midway",
               "short_name" : "Midway",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Henderson",
               "short_name" : "Henderson",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Clark County",
               "short_name" : "Clark County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Nevada",
               "short_name" : "NV",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "89011",
               "short_name" : "89011",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "US-95 & W Sunset Rd, Henderson, NV 89011, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0631541,
                  "lng" : -115.0303368
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0628498,
                  "lng" : -115.0303404
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 36.063002,
               "lng" : -115.0303386
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0643509302915,
                  "lng" : -115.0289896197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 36.0616529697085,
                  "lng" : -115.0316875802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJAzrYiuXQyIARIZcbN66ts10",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

but the real coordinates I need are: 36.063761 -115.032024.

Any advice how to get the road coordinates?

Comment: In your example the first item has type "route", it's not building. The position can be seen in Geocoder tool: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D36.063505%252C-115.033649. It look like this example works as expected.

Comment: Yes, but the wanted coordinate exclude from the results

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following recommendations for US roads formatting that you can find in

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_highways

So, in your case the search string should be "U.S. 95 & sunset, las vegas". The corresponding request will be (note URL-encoded search string)

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=U.S.%2095%20%26%20sunset%2C%20las%20vegas&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This request returns one result of type intersection as shown in my screenshot

[image]

You can also see this in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DU.S.%252095%2520%2526%2520sunset%252C%2520las%2520vegas

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome! I'll check it and let you know. BTW, any idea how to query i215 & Far Hills Ave (also Las Vegas)? I'm asking because in this section i215 is a co rd so it makes it more complicated (i215 can either be an Interstate highway or a country road 'Bruce Woodbury Beltway') .

Comment: Just realized it is not the wanted spot. I wanted 'W sunset Rd' and by default it returns 'Sunset Dr' which is a smaller road. Any way to prioritize results by road types? [this is the spot](https://www.google.com/maps/place/US-95,+Henderson,+NV+89014/@36.0659837,-115.0346698,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x80c8d0ee0715e219:0x20d1f9d85a2151ac!2sUS-95+%26+Veterans+Memorial+Hwy+%26+US-93,+Henderson,+NV+89014!3b1!8m2!3d36.0669328!4d-115.0341086!3m4!1s0x80c8d0ee15946fab:0xf63c089de79dc407!8m2!3d36.0659811!4d-115.0333684?hl=en)

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DU.S.%252095%2520%2526%2520W%2520sunset%2520rd%252C%2520las%2520vegas. You should format address as much precise as possible.

Comment: Yes, if I would have the full text ('w sunset rd') it will be great, but it is a free text so I need some fuzziness. Is it possible to rank results by road type (bigger to smaller)? PLZ see me first comment about 215&Far hills or 215&159. THANKS!